# ASP.NET Core MVC Identity - Make data displayed to users limited depending on what "group" they belong to?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have an application that is essentially a chore manager for households. Admins and users may register and add chores, finish them, delete, update etc.

The problem is that all of the data is shared for anyone accessing the application. What I want is to have users only see the data which is relevant to their household.

E.G. Admin registers and any users that register beneath them are put into a "group" where the data is shared amongst them, but if a new admin registers and other users register beneath them then their data is separate from the first group. For separate households, data is kept separate.

I am using ASP.NET Core MVC Identity to implement this, but couldn't find any tutorial online going over what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to achieve claims based authorization. Check this out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.2